# Setup home network for VNC

Tags: windows, macos, networking, wireless-networking, vnc

1. I own a macbook OS 10.10 and a desktop PC running Vista professional.
2. I use an USB 3g modem in order to have internet access (I could use it on both computers), but I usually connect the macbook to the net and use it as an hotspot trough WiFi in order to get the PC connected too.

Since I need use some Windows-only softwares, I usually use RealVNC in order to work from the mac which has a better screen readability and gives me the possibility to work anywhere I want in the house.

It's not a bad solution at the moment, but I'd like to know if there are better and more reliable possibilities. Like create a LAN network and use VNC through it, or via wireless (isn't this a problem since I already share the internet connection through it?).

Answer (score 0):

No, the fact that you share the internet access should not keep you from using vnc.

What you should avoid is having ethernet and Wifi connection in parallel. It could give you some headaches.

Answer (score 0):

If your PC is running Vista Professional it can be a [Remote Desktop server](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/remote-desktop-connection-faq#1TC=windows-vista).  Remote Desktop (RDP) would be much faster than VNC and would be more than fast enough over Wifi.  Microsoft has a [Remote Desktop Client in the Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-remote-desktop/id715768417?mt=12) so you can connect to your PC over RDP from the Mac.

The instructions from Microsoft's site are:

> 1. Open System by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start
>      button, clicking Control Panel, clicking System and Maintenance, and
>      then clicking System.
> 2. Click Remote settings on the left.
> 3. In the System Properties dialog box, under Remote Desktop, select
>      the one of the three options, and then click Select Users. 
>      Administrator permission required If you are prompted for an
>      administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide
>      confirmation.
> 4. If you are an administrator on the computer, your current user
>      account will automatically be added to the list of remote users and
>      you can skip the next two steps.
> 5. In the Remote Desktop Users dialog box, click Add.
> 6. In the Select Users or Groups dialog box, do the following:
> 7. To specify the search location, click Locations, and then select the
>      location you want to search.
> 8. In Enter the object names to select, type the name of the user that
>      you want to add, and then click OK.
> 9. The name will be displayed in the list of users in the Remote
>      Desktop Users dialog box.